# How to create a network bridge using command line in Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, bridge

I want create a network bridge using command line, I have tried "netsh bridge install" but the output says unsupported. After a google, I found this post at [here](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f31/creating-a-network-bridge-using-the-command-line-under-winxp-306164.html#post1784409), and also [here](http://www.inguardians.com/pubs/Vista_Wireless_Power_Tools-Wright.pdf). They all mentioned the nethelper tool but the [URL](http://winunix.mkreddys.com/create-network-bridge-through-command-line/) seem has broken. Some one knows where can get the tool or any other similar tools? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an official "Trial" version [download link](http://www.corecom.com/Software/) of Nethelper, Click " Download your free evaluation copy"

Answer (score 0):

Try program connectify.me in
http://en.softonic.com/s/connectify-me-full-version/windows-7
It has a bridge mode Option.
You have to try out it for yourself in a free test period, as I did not use this option yet.